# Multiprocessing: Responsiveness vs CPU load when using multiple while true queue.get() workers

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I have written a couple of examples of While True workers that fetch data from a queue. In principle the producers should behave something like below but in reality it is data from multiple ssl socket feeds so the producers here are for simulation purpose.

Fractions of milliseconds are important in my case and i am struggling in how to determine which of below alternatives (or some other alternative) is the best. I have understood that time slicing could effect responsiveness. When I am trying to run the code below all examples works well when it comes to CPU load except alternative 5 which eats 100% of my CPU.

This far my conclusion is that blocking .get() eats less CPU % than a non-blocking .get() given that the non-blocking .get() loop is set tight with very short sleep.

My goal is to implement code that will eat litte CPU time as well as being responsive to new updates. i.e., I would like one of the workers to do work within 0.1 millisecond from the time a new item arrives in the queue.

Sample code written in Python 2.7 for Windows 7 (note that I am using a 24 core machine so the numbers of workers might have to be adjusted down):

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time
import Queue


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.the_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.printerq = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def producer(self):
        i=0
        while True:
            self.the_queue.put(["hello",i],False)
            i=i+1
            time.sleep(1)

    'alternative 1'
    '''
    def worker_main(self):
        while True:
            try:
                item = self.the_queue.get(timeout=0.1)
            except Queue.Empty:
                time.sleep(0.0001) 
            else:
                self.printerq.put([item,os.getpid()],False)
    '''

    'alternative 2'
    '''
    def worker_main(self):
        while True:
            if not self.the_queue.empty():
                item = self.the_queue.get()
                #print os.getpid(), "got", item
                self.printerq.put([item,os.getpid()],False)
            time.sleep(0.0001)
    '''

    'alternative 3'

    def worker_main(self):
        while True:
            item = self.the_queue.get()
            self.printerq.put([item,os.getpid()],False)

    'alternative 4'
    '''
    def worker_main(self):
        while True:
            item = self.the_queue.get()
            self.printerq.put([item,os.getpid()],False)
            time.sleep(0.0001)
    '''

    'alternative 5 eats CPU 100%'
    '''
    def worker_main(self):
        while True:
            try:
                item = self.the_queue.get(False)
            except Queue.Empty:
                time.sleep(0.0001)
            else:
                self.printerq.put([item,os.getpid()],False)
                time.sleep(0.0001)
    '''

    def printer(self):
        while True:
            stuff=self.printerq.get()
            print stuff


if __name__=='__main__':
    mc=MyClass()

    process_printer = multiprocessing.Process(target=mc.printer, args=())
    process_printer.start() 

    for i in range(100):
        process_window = multiprocessing.Process(target=mc.worker_main, args=())
        process_window.start()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    for i in range(100):
        process_producer = multiprocessing.Process(target=mc.producer, args=())
        process_producer.start() 
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: "Fractions of milliseconds are important in my case" - are you sure Python is the right tool for the job?

Comment: I hope that it will work for the purpose...

Comment: I hope that it will work for the purpose... I have timed my calcualtion time to about 0.07ms. When i started coding it was about 6-7 seconds for each update. If I can make sure the application is responsive enough and can send https requests from the workers within 0.1ms then i would know my systems overall responsiveness would be around 0.2ms which is okay..

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely going to get the best performance by removing any `time.sleep()` calls. I would recommend using `queue.get()` which does a busy wait and use kill flags to end your processes. Your worker should look something like this:

```
def worker_main(self):
    while True:
        item = self.the_queue.get()
        # Checks for kill flag
        if item == None:
            break 
        self.printerq.put([item,os.getpid()],False)
```

This method requires that your producer put `None` into `self.the_queue`.  Yet because you have multiple producers, you may want to modify the workers such that they receive a kill flag from each producers. Something like:

```
def worker_main(self):
    kill_flags = 0        
    # Make sure to pass in num_producers
    while kill_flags < num_producers:
        item = self.the_queue.get()
        # Checks for kill flag
        if item == None:
            kill_flag += 1
            continue 
        self.printerq.put([item,os.getpid()],False)
```

As far as your producers go, a similar approach would work when they are done producing:

```
def producer(self):
    i=0
    while (some_condition_to_stop_producing):
        self.the_queue.put(["hello",i],False)
        i=i+1
        time.sleep(1)
    # Pass in the number of workers
    for i in range(num_workers):
        self.the_queue.put(None)
```

Don't forget that you will also need to modify the printer to end when you are done putting things into `printerq`.

Comment: Thanks Navidad20. Both for the answer and the edit. That was the solution i was leaning toward aswell. The one thing i am curious of is how this type of solution affects responsiveness in other processes/threads, how the cpu understands that it should switch between them and the systems waiting time before a switch would occur when using windows 7. Multiprocessing is a bit tricky when it comes to timing running time of an algo...

Comment: Have you considered timing each of your functions to see which ones take the longest? The `mulitprocessing.cpu_count` function can give you the number of logical cores running and thus you can assign the appropriate number of processes such that you won't have workers/producers waiting to get a process.